# How does CPython's refrerence counter work?

Tags: python, memory-management, garbage-collection, cpython

How does sys.getrefcount in Cpython work?

The following is expected

```
In [1]: numbers=[1,2,3]

In [2]: import sys

In [3]: sys.getrefcount(numbers)
Out[3]: 2
```

But I have difficulties in understanding the following numbers.

```
In [8]: n=3

In [9]: sys.getrefcount(n)
Out[9]: 443

In [10]: hello="hello"

In [11]: sys.getrefcount(hello)
Out[11]: 5
```

Any clarification? Some (see comments below) argue that one would not need to care what those references are. I am unsure -- how would one get an idea of how the garbage collection works in python, if we know little or are careless about the possible references to a variable.

Comment: Those objects just happen to have a bunch of other references you weren't aware of. You don't need to care what those references are.

Comment: integer pool, string interning, singletons (`sys.getrefcount(None)`) and constant folding are the most common explanation for reference counts > 2.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Thanks, but how would one get an idea of how the garbage collection works in python, if we know little or are careless about the possible references to a variable?

Comment: *You*, the programmer, don't need to know them. The runtime itself checks the reference count every time it is decremented. If it hits 0, the object is collected. Periodically, the pool of objects is scanned to look for reference cycles (objects with non-zero reference counts that only reference each other). Such cycles can be collected as well.